# Explain me its usage please

Tags: phrases, subcontinental-english, contemporary-english

At their instance, three other associates were subsequently nabbed.

Here, what does, 'at their instance' mean?

Comment: It means someone misheard or mistranscribed *insistence*.

Comment: Could you  please elaborate your explanation? I still don't get it.

Comment: Wherever you got the sentence, someone made a mistake (if you copied it from somewhere, then the author made a mistake; if you heard it and wrote it down, then you probably made a mistake). The mistake is that the word "instance" should be "insistence". Look up "insistence", and that should clear up any remaining doubts.

Comment: I read this in today's newspaper 'The Hindu' . As a matter of fact I happened to come across the same thing twice in the same newspaper in two different news. I tried searching it online but could not find anything helpful.

Comment: This article, then: ['Dhoom' gang busted](http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Delhi/dhoom-gang-busted/article8830356.ece)?  The last paragraph? Yeah, all I can say is that that's not standard in any variety of English I'm familiar with (AmE and BrE). I've never seen it before. Either it's an error on the part of the author of the article, or it's a feature of IndE.

Comment: Yes, exactly that one. Please answer if you happen to know anything about it in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Because the verb *explain* does not work like the verb *tell*, you cannot say “Explain me something” as you have attempted to do. This is a common error in new learners. Unlike with *tell*, you cannot use an indirect object with *explain*, but must use a prepositional phrase instead. *Explain to me something, explain something to me, explain something for me, explain for me something* all work (although not all are equally common), but what you have only works if you change the verb from *explain* to *tell*. I suggest you check out our sister site [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

The word *instance* here appears to mean [*request* (*FULL* definition of *instance* in Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instance).

> Example: am writing to you at the *instance* of my client

Comment: Not likely. MW marks this use as archaic.

Comment: In the alternatives provided by MW, I have quoted 1(b) which is *not* marked archaic. 1(a) is marked archaic instead.

Comment: You're right about MW. The *OED* makes the word archaic in this sense except in the phrase *at the instance of* [some person]* as in your quote in which person=*client*. The full quote from the paper is *The suspects initially denied their involvement in crimes, but when presented with the CCTV footage, they allegedly confessed. At their instance, their three other associates were subsequently nabbed.* It seems odd to describe their likely-coerced testimony as a request, but perhaps this is common in Indian English.